# Understanding socket names

Tags: sockets, networking, network-programming

> Socket names are **strings** and appear in the file system name space through portals.

from http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.progcomm%2Fdoc%2Fprogcomc%2Fskt_comms.htm

> The **bind** call is used to assign a name to a socket on the local side of a connection.

from http://osr507doc.sco.com/en/netguide/dusockD.binding_names.html

```
int bind(int socket, const struct sockaddr *address, socklen_t address_len);
```

from the man page of bind.

What EXACTLY are the socket "names"? And do we "set" them?

The bind system call, doesn't seem to have an argument for specifying a name, does it?

Comment: Which development technology you are using?

Comment: @Emaad Linux with gcc compiler. Suse 11.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's common that the function which acturally opens the socket returns a handle/identifier(socket descriptor) for future references.
As the link you posted describes:

```
bind(s, name, namelen);

The argument s in the line above is the socket descriptor returned from the socket() call.
```

I think it's just a custom name for the `socket descriptor`, and therefore optional. Probably also depends on what you're about to do, if you need it.

Comment: My point was, that there is no argument resembling "name" in the bind call, shown by the man page, then how to set it?

Comment: The function expects 3 arguments: `int bind(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr *my_addr, socklen_t addrlen);` taken from http://linux.die.net/man/2/bind First one is the socket handle, second the name and the third is the length of the given name.

Comment: But the first link I have posted in OP says that name is a string, but the bind's 2nd arg is shown as struct! string != struct.

Comment: The first link describes the unix file system: `Socket names are strings and appear in the file system name space through portals.` It does not describe any programming aspects. The link I posted also has an example.